# R: Function changing print behavior when returning NULL

Tags: r, printing, null, return-value

This question is only for curiosity. My colleague and I were trying to write a function which returns `NULL`, but doesn't print it.

Before we found `return(invisible(NULL))`, I tried `return({dummy<-NULL})` which works, but only once. After the first evaluation, the functions starts printing again:

```
test <- function() {
  return({x<-NULL})
}
# no printout
test()
# with printout
test()
# with printout
test()
```

How does this come about?

Comment: did u call the function for any number of times in code?

Comment: I dont understand your question sai. OP says he calls the function n-times. The first time nothing is printed any time after `NULL` is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to some older return handling built into R. There are many return functions, `withVisible`, `invisible`, etc. When you return an assignment `x<-null` inside the return function it will not automatically print. If you want an assignment to print...

```
test <- function() {
  withAutoprint(x<-NULL)
}
# with printout this time
test()
# with printout
test()
# with printout
test()
```

I think this just may be hard coded into the return function, maybe pulling something from this logic below, just a shot in the dark though.

```
Source: R Documentation

x <- 1
withVisible(x <- 1) # *$visible is FALSE
x
withVisible(x)      # *$visible is TRUE
```

Again if we do not use an expression and simply return a variable or value inside our return function we get automatic printing. The reason I am guessing it returns on a second call has to do with the fact x was already assigned previously.

**EDIT:** I found this deep into the documentation on auto printing. **"Whether the returned value of a top-level R expression is printed is controlled by the global boolean variable R_Visible. This is set (to true or false) on entry to all primitive and internal functions based on the eval column of the table in file src/main/names.c: the appropriate setting can be extracted by the macro PRIMPRINT."**([Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-ints.html#Autoprinting))

Comment: Learning something new everyday :)